# Merging objects from one array into another based on matching object values

Tags: jquery, arrays

How can I use jQuery to merge the following two arrays on `child_array.cat_parent_id == parent_array.cat_id`?

The parent_array:

```
[{
  "cat_name" : "Fruit",
  "cat_id" : 77
}, {
  "cat_name" : "Vegetables",
  "cat_id" : 221
}]
```

And the child_array which I'd like to have merged into parent_array:

```
[{
  "cat_name" : "Bananas",
  "cat_id" : 79,
  "cat_parent_id" : 77
},{
  "cat_name" : "Apples",
  "cat_id" : 80,
  "cat_parent_id" : 77
}, {
  "cat_name" : "Carrots",
  "cat_id" : 222,
  "cat_parent_id" : 221
}]
```

Here's what I would like the output to look like:

```
[{
  "cat_name" : "Fruit",
  "cat_id" : 77,
  "cat_children": [
     {
       "cat_name" : "Bananas",
       "cat_id" : 79
     },
     {
       "cat_name" : "Apples",
       "cat_id" : 80
     }
  ]
}, {
  "cat_name" : "Vegetables",
  "cat_id" : 221,
  "cat_children": [
     {
       "cat_name" : "Carrots",
       "cat_id" : 222
     }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this problem?  What part of the solution are you stuck on?

Comment: Nested loops should do it. It would be easier if you turned the parent array into an object whose keys are the category IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need jQuery to do this... just write some nested loops and do some checks. Your JSON structure can be greatly optimized to achieve this, but the following function will achieve it the way it is:

```
function merge(_parent,_children){
    var result = _parent;
  for(x in _children){
    var parentID = _children[x].cat_parent_id;
    for(y in _parent){
      if(_parent[y].cat_id == parentID){      
        if(!result[y].cat_children){
            result[y].cat_children = [];
        }
        result[y].cat_children.push(_children[x]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - nice and straightforward. I had to change the for loops to the `for (var x = 0; x < _children.length; x++)` format to avoid getting duplicate child objects, but maybe that has something to do with my specific setup.

Comment: Glad it worked! There is a way to make this fully dynamic as well in case you change your object keys, but for this specific application, it's good to go.